# grunt csscomb not processing all scss files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, glob

I've tried to set up a grunt csscomb task, but I'm not sure if I'm getting the globbing pattern right:

```
csscomb: {
    dynamic_mappings: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'app/',
        src: '**/*.scss',
        dest: 'app/assets/tempcomb'
    },
    options: {
      config: 'csscomb.json'
    }
},
```

Here is my folder architecture:

```
app
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── imports
│   │   │   ├── helpers
│   │   │   │   └── _helpers.scss
│   │   │   ├── layout
│   │   │   │   ├── _fonts.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── _grid.scss
│   │   │   │   └── _reset.scss
│   │   │   └── modules
│   │   │       ├── _dev.scss
│   │   │       ├── _indicators.scss
│   │   │       ├── _modal.scss
│   │   │       ├── _nav.scss
│   │   │       └── _ref.scss
│   │   ├── main.scss
│   │   └── pages
│   │       ├── bibliography.scss
│   │       ├── cover.scss
│   │       ├── example.scss
│   │       ├── examples
│   │       │   ├── _bar-graph.scss
│   │       │   ├── _modal-transitions.scss
│   │       │   ├── _modals.scss
│   │       │   ├── _scroll-end-animation.scss
│   │       │   ├── _scrollable.scss
│   │       │   └── _tabs.scss
│   │       ├── index.scss
│   │       └── prescribing-information.scss
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   ├── tempcomb
```

What I want it to do is look at all the directories under `app`, take all the `scss` files and write them to `tempcomb` while also maintaining the folder structure.

Currently it replicates the folder structure fine, but it only outputs the `scss` files that are in the `layout` folder.

If anyone could explain to me why this is happening it would be much appreciated!

P.s. before the task runs, the `tempcomb` folder doesn't exist. I've just added it to the architecture diagram to show where it ends up.

Comment: Such as **/**/*.scss ?

Comment: I have tried that too and it just does the same thing, but yes that's what I'm aiming for

Comment: I only use gulp, but do you build up the path from public directory?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-recursive-compass

Comment: Do you mean look at the way the globbing is done there or is that task something you think i should be using?

Comment: both I think. An alternative is adding the path's to the src array. Second alternative is: adding **/ twice to your src path

Comment: I've tried adding ** twice and the problem with specifying paths is that it won't account for new directories added in the future.